# Getting text in paragraph by searching for text in bold tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get text from a paragraph and I'm currently using         driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Definition')]").text

However, the problem is that the html is in the following format:

```
<p>
   <b> Definition: </b>
"text that i also need to get"
</p>
```

Currently, my code is only fetching the text in the bold tag. Is there a way to get the entire paragraph using the text in the bold tag to search? There are no ids or classes in the part that I need to look through,  so I cannot search by those.

Answer (score 0):

What is being returned? I am not familiar with this library, but if the tags and inner text are returned then you could potentially define a string as `<b> Definition: </b>`. Then use the same method to get the outer `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the `bold_tag` element defined (not the text value, but the specific element you are interested in itself) you could try this:

```
p_tag = bold_tag.find_element_by_xpath("./..") # go up a level to <p> parent
print(p_tag.text)
```

EDIT: I re-read your OP and it looks like you do have it defined, so the full code would look like this:

```
bold_tag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//b[contains(text(), 'Definition:']")
p_tag = bold_tag.find_element_by_xpath("./..") # go up a level to <p> parent
print(p_tag.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
xPathResult = document.evaluate('//b[text()=" Definition: "]/parent::p', document);
if (xPathResult) {
  p_tag_parent = xPathResult.iterateNext();
  console.log(p_tag_parent.innerText);

}
```

```html
<p>
  <b> Definition: </b> "text that i also need to get"
</p>
```

You can search the element that has Definition: and then get the parent that is p.

```
p_tag_parent_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//b[text()=" Definition: "]/parent::p').text;
```